An inequality related to three vectors in an Euclidean space
I have to show that when $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if
$\|x\|,\|y\|,\|z\|\geq1$ then at least one of $\|x+y\|,\|x+z\|,\|y+z\|$ is greater than or equal to 1.
It's obvious for $\|z\| \geq \frac{3}{2} $, but I couldn't prove it for general case. I assumed $\|x-z\|,\|y-z\| < 1$ and tried to prove $\|x+y\| \geq 1$, but failed after a long time of manipulating meaningless inequalities. When $n=2$, I know that the inequality must hold since two vectors $x,y$ are contained in the radius-1-ball centered at $z$ yielding 'small angle' between them, less than $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. This gave me the desired inequality. However, I couldn't genelize it to arbitrary dimension. I expect that there must be an algebraic solution.
Thank you in advance!

What does the notation mean on the right hand side of the implication? Are you saying that it is not true that any of those are less than one or that it is not true that all of them are less than one?

I'm sorry for ambiguity. It means that "not all" of three norms are less than 1, that is, at least one of them must be greater than or equal to 1.

Please, edit your question and use either quantifiers to clarify that, or even better use words to make it concise and clear.

Also, unless you include your work on the problem, expect to receive downvotes and the eventual closing of your question.

Thank you for your comment, I edited my question.

Let us suppose $\|x\|, \|y\|, \|z\| \ge 1$, and $\|x+y\|, \|y+z\|, \|x+z\| \le 1$. Recall the polarisation identity:
$$\langle x, y \rangle  = \frac{1}{2}(\|x + y\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2).$$
Therefore, using the polarisation identity
\begin{align}
0 &\le \|x + y + z\|^2 \\
&= \|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2 + 2\langle x, y \rangle + 2\langle x, z \rangle + 2\langle y, z \rangle \\
&= \|x + y\|^2 + \|y + z\|^2 + \|x + z\|^2 - \|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2 - \|z\|^2 \\
&\le 1 + 1 + 1 + (-1) + (-1) + (-1) = 0.
\end{align}
So, the only way this can possibly happen is if $x + y + z = 0$. In this case, $x + y = -z$, so
$$1 \ge \|x + y\| = \|z\| \ge 1.$$
Similar observations show that $\|x + y\| = \|y + z\| = \|x + z\| = 1$, and so the stronger condition, that all three are strictly less than $1$, cannot occur. Thus, by contradiction, the result holds.

Let $s=x_1+x_2+x_3$ and $a_i=s-x_i.$ Observe $a_1+a_2+a_3=2s.$ Suppose that $\|a_i\|< 1\leq\|x_i\|$ for $i=1,2,3.$ Then $0< \|x_i\|^2-\|a_i\|^2=\|s\|^2-2\langle s,a_i\rangle.$ Summing we get $$0<3\|s\|^2-2\langle s,2s\rangle =-\|s\|^2$$ a contradiction. Therefore $\max_i (\|a_i\|)\geq 1.$

We can think of what happens to a pair of vectors $\|x\|,\|y\| \geq 1$ under addition, given the angle between them, call it $\theta_{x,y}$. When $\theta_{x,y} = \pi/2$, the vectors are perpendicular, and $\|x+y\| \geq 1$ since the first vector leaves the unit $n$-ball, and the second vector does nothing to bring it back to the origin. When $\theta_{x,y} < \pi/2$, the angle between vectors is acute (think of them as pointing in generally the same direction), and $\|x+y\| > 1$. The last case is $\theta_{x,y} > \pi/2$, where it is possible that their sum is not of magnitude $\geq 1$.
So consider three vectors $\|x\|,\|y\|, \|z\| \geq 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We will force the result by trying to construct a case where all pairs achieve a sum less than $1$. To do this, choose the vectors such that $\theta_{x,y} > \pi/2$ and in such a way that $\|x+y\|<1$. Then we have 3 choices of $\theta_{x,z}$:

If $\theta_{x,z} = \pi/2$, then we are forced $\|x+z\| \geq 1$ by the reasoning above.

If $\theta_{x,z} < \pi/2$, then we are forced $\|x+z\| \geq 1$ by the reasoning above.

If $\theta_{x,z} > \pi/2$, then $\theta_{y,z} < \pi/2$ and we are forced $\|y+z\| \geq 1$ by the reasoning above.


Hence at least one pair's sum leaves the unit ball as desired.
